# What is the recommended javascript framework to develop a web application with Spring Framework?

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, web-applications, frontend

I will soon start developing a web application that will have a desktop version and a mobile version and currently I am deciding the architecture.

For the server part, I will use Java, with Spring framework, the database will be MySQL. My big question is the JavaScript framework that I will use for this project. I have experience with ExtJS but the license costs are high for a startup.

What similar to ExtJS frameworks that recommend? I will have to develop an application for the desktop version and another application for smartphones / tablet version? Or have a way to reuse code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These might be a helpful links in your case:

[spring architecture presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/martinlippert/modern-architectures-with-spring-and-javascript)

[angular vs backbone vs ember](http://jonathanmh.com/best-javascript-mvc-frameworks-2013-2014/)

[more angular vs backbone vs ember](http://readwrite.com/2014/02/06/angular-backbone-ember-best-javascript-framework-for-you)

Apart from using a clientside MCV javascript framework to communicate directly with spring, I have also seen people using an additional proxy server inbetween spring and the client framework for bigger and more complex projects (.eg angular.js -> [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/#/) -> spring).

I guess its all about what u are up to create.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com) this is the goto framework for me, you can find examples of integrating jQuery and Spring via a quick search. Also jQuery has support for iOS and Android according to the website, although I have not implemented it on iOS or Android

Comment: It's easy to build grids with pagination in jQuery? Do you use another framework to apply efects in the UI components?